# Retrieving SharePoint 2013 List Data from Sharepoint provider hosted app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, splistitem

I have created a SharePoint 2013 provider hosted app using visual studio. It don't use the web parts. I have to retrieve the data from the SharePoint 2013 list residing on the SharePoint site collection.I can do that with visual web part by this code

```
 private DataTable GetItemDetails()
 {
      SPWeb spweb = SPContext.Current.Web;
      SPList ticketsList = spweb.GetList("[http://git-hub/sites/mysiteName/Lists/CalendarList/AllItems]");
      return ticketsList.Items.GetDataTable();
 }
```

This gave me table of items and I used that table to get the required data. But the problem is now I want use same data my SharePoint app which is made of asp.net pages with c# code behind. I used the same code but it giving me error like
 "

> Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify
>   that you are running in a 64-bit executable."
>   Even I am using any plate form in app build settings. Please let me know if any way I can retrieve the list data in asp.net page to show the user their schedules.

Comment: Hi, I just found the solution for this question with the help of my colleagues. We used the web service of SharePoint Providing. 
Here is the link to get the web service.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx
Here is the link to the very helpful blog which describe how to use this
http://sarangasl.blogspot.ca/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html

Thanks. Hopefully it will save the someone day. As it took me day to get to this result.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Managed client object model :

```
Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        List<string> listOfUsers = new List<string>();


        using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
        {

            List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItem);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
            {
                listview.Add(string.Format("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["Title"]));
            }

            ListList.DataSource = listOfUsers;
            ListList.DataBind();

        }
```